# error factor predictors must have at most 32 levels?

Tags: tree, classification

Please let me know how to solve the problem of Error in tree(as.factor(RainTomorrow) ~ ., weather, subset = train) : factor predictors must have at most 32 levels

> 

I want Fit a classification tree to this data training set 70%, with “RainTomorrow” as the response and the other variables as predictors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiJpZ.png)
Thank you

> 

I want Fit a classification tree to this data training set 70%, with “RainTomorow” as the response and the other variables as predictors